# Rails image upload from iphone application using json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am using Rails database for an iPhone application. I have created a controller:

```
def create
  @photomsg = Photomsg.new(photo_params)

  if @photomsg.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(@photomsg, :notice => 'photomsg was     successfully created.') }
      format.json { render :json => @photomsg, :status => 1, :data => ''} 
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(@photomsg, :notice => 'photomsg was fail to created.') }
      format.json { render :json => @photomsg.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity} 

    end
  end
end
```

And params is

```
private
  def photo_params
    params.require(:photomsg).permit(:title, :image, :physician, :patient)
  end
```

I was used paperclip for the image upload, Model is look like

```
class Photomsg < ActiveRecord::Base     
attr_accessor :image_data

    has_attached_file :image, styles: {medium: ["300x300>", :png], thumb: ["100x100>", :png]}
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
    before_save :decode_image_data

    def decode_image_data
    # If image_data is present, it means that we were sent an image over
    # JSON and it needs to be decoded.  After decoding, the image is     processed
# normally via Paperclip.
if self.image_data.present?
    data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(self.image_data))
    data.class.class_eval {attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type}
    data.original_filename = self.id.to_s + ".png"
    data.content_type = "image/png"

    self.image = data
end
  end
end
```

The image and other fields upload is working fine on the web, but when send those data from iPhone application as POST method the not working I am using the below url for the JSON url:

http://infinite-depths-5848.herokuapp.com/photomsgs

The route is like below

```
resources :photomsgs
```

Comment: is the data sent as mutipart? if not, the post request does not deliver the file data

Comment: Yes the whole image is come in single string using base 64

Comment: ok if we leave image upload, how can only other data is store, like other fields

Comment: i dont understand the last comment